# Drupal 7 ajax form submit not working

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I have a node page where I need to create a reply form via ajax for commenting. Commenting in my system is also a kind of node.

When my page first loads it's presented with all comments done and also only one textbox & submit button which is used to add a new comment node. When I click submit button that comment is added via ajax.

Below each comments there is reply option. When I click on this reply, an ajax call is made to bring a new text area & reply button which are coming using same node form that is presented in form above. When this new form is presented I fill it up and submit at that time it's not submitted via ajax instead it redirects to destination URL.

Following is my menu & form alter code.

```
function mymodule_menu() {

    $items['user_reply_comments/%/%'] = array(
        'title' => t('Reply to User Comment'),
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_user_reply_comment',
        'page arguments' => array(1, 2, 3),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
        'file' => 'includes/mymodule.pages.inc',
    );

    return $items;

}


function mymodule_form_comment_node_statement_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.form');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
    drupal_add_js($base_url. '/' .path_to_theme().'/js/script.js', 'file');
    $form['#action'] = url('user_reply_comments/'.$id.'/'.arg(2) .'/ajax');
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'mymodule_comment_node_statement_form_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'comment-replies-' . arg(2),
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'click',
        'progress' => array('type'=> 'throbber', 
            'message' => "<div></div>",
        ),
        'js' => array(
            $base_url. '/' .path_to_theme().'/js/script.js',
        ),
    );
}


/**
 * Ajax callback for comment_node_statement_form.
 */
function mymodule_comment_node_statement_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {   
    /*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($form);
    exit;*/
    //echo ' 1 :' . arg(1) . '      2:' .arg(2); exit; // sub reply dows not came here
  $message_empty = drupal_get_messages();
  if(!empty($message_empty) && isset($message_empty ['error'])){
    global $base_url;
    $command_add = array();
    if(user_is_anonymous()){
        $command_add = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "redirect_user", array($base_url));
    }
    return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
            ajax_command_before('#content', '<div id="inline-messages" class="messages error">'.$message_empty ['error'] [0].'</div>'),
            ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "greyout_reply"),
            $command_add
        )
    );
  }
  else{

      $current_path = TRUE;
      $statement_page_reply_form = "";
      $pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "statements");
      if($pos !== FALSE){
        $current_path = FALSE;
      }
     // print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
     // print "$$$".$current_path."@@@"; exit;
      // Clear the messages (drupal_set_message() doens't work for some reason).
      $_SESSION['messages'] = '';
      if($current_path){
        $html = "<div class='arrow'>arrow</div>";
      }
      else{
        $html = "";
      }
      $id = $form['#node']->nid;
      if (!empty($form['build_info_args_' . $id]['#value'])) {
        $form_state = array(
          'build_info' => array('args' => $form['build_info_args_' . $id]['#value']),
          'values' => array(),
        ) + form_state_defaults();
      }
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
      //$comment_form = drupal_rebuild_form('comment_node_statement_form', $form_state, $form);
      $comment_form = drupal_rebuild_form('comment_node_statement_form', $form_state, $form);
      $node_comments = views_embed_view('statement_replies', 'block', $id);
      if($form['current_url']['#value'] == "dashboard"){
        $comment_form['current_url'] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => "dashboard", '#name' => 'current_url');
        $html .= '<div class="dashboard-statements-comments">';
      }
      if($current_path){
        $html .= '<div class="statement-comment-reply-box">'.drupal_render($comment_form).'</div>';
      }
      else{
        $statement_page_reply_form = '<div class="arrow">arrow</div><div class="statement-comment-reply-box">'. drupal_render($comment_form).'</div>';
        $num_comments = db_query("SELECT COUNT(cid) AS count FROM {comment} WHERE nid =:nid and status = :status",array (":nid"=>$id, ":status" => '1'))->fetchField();
        $statement_page_reply_form .= '<span class="statement_total_replies">'.$num_comments. ' Replies</span>';
        $statement_page_reply_form .= '<span class="collapse_reply">COLLAPSE</span>';
      }
      $html .= '<div class="statement-comment-reply-feed">'.$node_comments.'</div>';
      if($form['current_url']['#value'] == "dashboard"){
        $html .= '</div>';
      }

      if($current_path){ 
        return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
                ajax_command_html('#statement-replies-' . $id, $html),
                ajax_command_remove('#inline-messages'),
                ajax_command_before('#content', '<div id="inline-messages" class="messages status"><h2 class="element-invisible">Status message</h2>Reply posted.</div>'),
            )
        );
      }
      else{
        return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
          ajax_command_html('#statement-replies-' . $id, $html),
          ajax_command_html('.statement_upper_part .reply_form_statement', $statement_page_reply_form),
          ajax_command_remove('#inline-messages'),
          ajax_command_before('#content', '<div id="inline-messages" class="messages status"><h2 class="element-invisible">Status message</h2>Reply posted.</div>'),
          ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "alter_elements"),

        )
        );
      }
   }
}


/**
 * This is function in mymodule.pages.inc
 * Callback function for 'user_reply_comment/%/%' path.
 * 
 * Returns the popup modal form consists of reply form
 * 
 * @param $entity_id
 *   Integer representing node ID
 * @param $current_cid
 *   Integer representing comment ID
 */
function mymodule_user_reply_comment($entity_id, $current_cid, $js = FALSE) {

    $logged_in = user_is_logged_in();
    $node = node_load($entity_id); 
    if($node) {
        if ($node->type == 'statement' || $node->type == "user_comment") {          
            $replies = "<div class='arrow'>arrow</div>";
            $ajax_css = "";
            if ($logged_in) {
              $edit = array('nid' => $node->nid);
              $form = drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) $edit);
              $replies .= "<div class='statement-comment-reply-box'>";
              $replies .= drupal_render($form);
              $replies .= "</div>";
            }
            else{
                $ajax_css = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "views_row_hide_border");
            }

            $replies .= "<div class='statement-comment-reply-feed'>";
            $replies .= "</div>";

            return array(
              '#type' => 'ajax',
              '#commands' => array(
                  ajax_command_html('#comment-replies-' . $current_cid, $replies),
                  ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "show_statement_replies", array('#comment-replies-' . $current_cid)),
                  ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "toggle_reply_links" , array($current_cid)),
                  ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "mymodule_user_reply_comment_reply" , array($current_cid, $edit)),
                  $ajax_css
              ));
        }
    } 
}

/*
Following is there in script.js file
*/

(function($) {
  $.fn.mymodule_user_reply_comment_reply = function(cid, nid) {
    var form_class = '.comment-form-' + nid + '--' + cid;
    var button = form_class + ' input.form-submit';
    console.log('reply thread click.' + cid);
    $(button).bind('click', 'upload_reply_image');
    /*{
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        return false;  
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropogation();
        //Drupal.attachBehaviors($(form_class));
        return false;
    });//*/
    console.log('reply thread out.' + cid);
  };
})(jQuery);


/* To toggle between Reply expand/collapse mode in statement/Comment box and their reply box - Start */
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggle_reply_links = function(cid) {
        jQuery('#close-sub-comments-' + cid).parent().find('a').toggle();
    };
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
    $.fn.show_statement_replies = function(id) {
        jQuery(id).slideDown();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong path in your code. You need to change this in hook_menu:

```
 $items['user_reply_comments/%/%'] = array(
```

With this:

```
 $items['user_reply_comments/%/%/ajax'] = array(
```

At least there's something that doesn't match in my opinion.
Clear your menu cache to see the changes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have used "ajax" in hook_menu() and clear the cache but still it did not work.